# Does the JLS explicitly deny to declare the same class name in the same package twice?

Tags: java

The following code doesn't compile:

```
class A
{
    class A{ };
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/bYgWjl)

But The [JLS 6.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4) denies apperaing of a class with the same name for only local classes:

> It is a compile-time error if the name of a local class C is used to
>   declare a new local class within the scope of C, unless the new local
>   class is declared within another class whose declaration is within the
>   scope of C.

Does the JLS explcicitly define the rule to prevent the code I provided be compiled?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76938670/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-following-rule-in-jls-if-another-rule-makes-it-redund. Also, your case is about declaring nested classes with the same name. The real answer to your question as stated would be: It is a compile-time error if the name of a top level class or interface appears as the name of any other top level class or interface declared in the same package from Section 7.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, from [Class Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1)

> It is a compile-time error if a class has the same simple name as any of its enclosing classes or interfaces.