# What is the meaning of the following rule in JLS if another rule makes it redundant?

Tags: java, jls

In JLS 17, [Section 6.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4), it says (emphasis mine):

> It is a compile-time error if the name of a local class or interface C is used to declare a new local class or interface within the scope of C, **unless the new local class or interface is declared within a class or interface declaration appearing within the scope of C**

Meanwhile in [Section 8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1):

> It is a compile-time error if a class has the same simple name as any of its enclosing classes or interfaces.

Although logically there is no contradiction, I wonder what is the point of having that "unless" clause in the first rule when the second one is going to result in compilation error anyway when the condition for "unless" is not satisfied? Perhaps I am missing something?

For example:

```
class Test {
  public void foo() {
    class C {
      public void bar() {
        class SomeNested {
          public void xyz() {
            class C{} // Section 6.4 says nothing what happens in this case. Section 8.1 results in compilation error
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The first rule is more specific and declares exceptions to the second rule for local classes only.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks for the comment. How is that useful? It only confuses and disseminates rules across JLS, doesn't it?

Comment: I agree that the current implementation seems to only follow rule 8.1, which means the implementation fails to meet the exception defined in JLS 6.4. Whether or not that means the JLS should be updated, or the implementation should be fixed, I don't know. As to how it is useful, I don't know, I hardly ever use local classes, and I can't think of a time when I had classes nested in local classes (except maybe anonymous classes), but I assume rule 6.4 was put there for a reason.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thank you. I have the same understanding and it raised a question why would JLS put that part of 6.4 there if it only follows 8.1 since I couldn't find any other cases that would justify existence of 6.4. "but I assume rule 6.4 was put there for a reason" <- I am here to look for that reason as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Mark Rotteveel is correct: the rules in 6.4 are actually relaxing the normal 8.1 rule about nested classes.  This is clear from the (non-normative) paragraph that follows the 8.1 rule that you quoted:

> *"These rules allow redeclaration of a variable, local class, or local interface in nested class or interface declarations that occur in the scope of the variable, local class, or local interface; such nested class or interface declarations may be local class or interface declarations (§14.3) or anonymous class declarations (§15.9.5). Thus, the declaration of a formal parameter, local variable, local class, or local interface may be shadowed in a class or interface declaration nested within a method, constructor, or lambda expression; and the declaration of an exception parameter may be shadowed in a class or interface declaration nested within the Block of the catch clause."*

Clearly, the 6.4 rule is not redundant.  It is allowing a form of shadowing that is otherwise forbidden (by 8.1).  To the extent<sup>1</sup> that 6.4 contradicts 8.1, the text above implies that intended meaning is that 6.4 should override 8.1 for local classes.

---

<sup>1 - There may also be a way of reading 6.4 so that it doesn't contradict 8.1; e.g. some fine distinction between enclosing classes and enclosing methods.  However, I couldn't find a convincing justification for that. It is also *possible* that the facial contradiction is due to an editorial issue, and the spec and/or the compiler is wrong.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your comment. FYI: I am not questioning all rules in 6.4 but only the part cited in the question. Now, while I understand the intention behind the rules in 6.4, I couldn't find any evidence how is the cited rule from 6.4 either practically or theoretically useful to justify its existence in JLS. If we can't find any, doesn't it make the rule, or at least the part after the "unless" connective, redundant?

Comment: "It is allowing a form of shadowing that is otherwise forbidden (by 8.1)" - however due to 8.1, we can't achieve that shadowing, can we? Seems like a feature that is not reachable.

Comment: When reading the JLS you need to read the context; e.g. the non-normative text and the examples.  In this case, the normative text tells you the purpose of the rules.  And they justify their existence ....

Comment: "however due to 8.1, we can't achieve that shadowing, can we?".  To the extent that 8.1 and 6.4 are contradictory, the intention is that 6.4 overrides 8.1.  That is how I read it.  You may read it some other way ... but I don't think it was the authors intention to write a deliberately contradictory specification.

Comment: okay, I got it now. The 6.4 takes the precedence although I believe ideally it should be clear immediately from the normative part. But the compiler seems to fail to follow that, is that a bug?

Comment: If the compiler doesn't behave according to what the spec says, that is a bug (in either the compiler or the spec).  Submit a bug report via the OpenJDK with a clearly argued explanation of why you claim that the spec and compiler are in conflict.   (I have no skin in this game.)

Comment: I will think about it a bit more before submitting a bug - don't want to look like a fool :D However, so far it looks like a bug or redundancy at its best since the compiler has no impact from the 6.4 rule. Will do my best, thank you!